# 'Inheriting' function parameters

Tags: java, language-agnostic

I think this is kinda language-agnostic, but I'd like to know how this feature works in Java.

Let's suppose I have a function that reads a file using a Scanner:

```java
void printFile(Scanner s) {
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

So, if I have several ways to simulate a file, using this function would be

```java
String content = "foo\nbar\n";
printFile(new Scanner(content));

File file = new File("my/file.txt");
printFile(new Scanner(file));

InputStream input = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/a.txt").openStream();
printFile(new Scanner(input));
```

My question is, if I have several ways to simulate this file, how do I make it easier to use this function without having to enter `new Scanner()` every time I call it?

Some observations:

- This would be useful in two ways: ease of writing unit tests and simplifying the API for the user.
- Overloading the function solves the problem, however if the original function has several overloads, this could make the code ugly and/or complicate writing code, where the developer would have to read the documentation, write a corresponding overload and repeat.

Comment: I don't see why calling `new` is a problem.  Calling `new` and creating an object allows the caller to be specific about what the caller wants passed in.  If you changed your function signature to something `printFile(Object o)` then you might not be able to guarantee what the results of calling `Scanner` might be.

Comment: I think it's boilerplate code. Moreover, it's makes more sense calling `printFile(file)` than `printFile(new Scanner(file))`.

Comment: You'd have to create an overload for each type you'd want to accept: `void printFile(URL url)`, and `void printFile(File file)`. These would each delegate to the `void printFile(Scanner)` method. To avoid the overloads, you would need to create an adapter wrapper object, which is essentially what `Scanner` is acting as in your case.